# Check profile author's role and apply image based on it

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have this code that checks the user role and adds an image to the page based on the current logged in user browsing the page:

```
 global $current_user; 
 get_currentuserinfo();
 switch (true)  {
  case ( user_can( $current_user, "talento_pro") ):
    echo '<i class="fa fa-bolt" title="Agência PRO+"></i>';
  break;
  case ( user_can( $current_user, "talento_pro_plus") ):
    echo '<i class="fa fa-rocket" title="Agência PRO+"></i>';
  break;
}
```

How can I reproduce the same, but instead of checking the current logged in user, it checks the role of the user who originally created the page the logged in one is browsing?

**EDITED**

I've tweaked the code a little bit but it isn't working, I think it's headed on the right direction?

```
global $authordata; 
get_the_author_meta( "user_level" = "talento_pro" );

switch (true)  {
 case ( user_can( $authordata, "talento_pro") ):
   echo '<i title="Talento PRO" class="fa fa-bolt"></i>';
 break;
 case ( user_can( $author, "talento_pro_plus") ):
   echo '<i title="Talento PRO+" class="fa fa-rocket"></i>';
 break;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change a few things:

1. You don't need both the `global $authordata` and `get_the_author_meta`. You can pick one to use.
2. The way you are trying to get the author meta is incorrect. You just need to pass `user_level` like `get_the_author_meta( 'user_level' );`

Try this:

```
    global $authordata;
    // This assumes that each user only has one role. You might have to adjust what array value you get
    $author_role = $authordata->roles[0];

        switch( $author_role ) {
            case 'talento_pro':
                echo '<i title="Talento PRO" class="fa fa-bolt"></i>';
                break;
            case 'talento_pro_plus':
                echo '<i title="Talento PRO+" class="fa fa-rocket"></i>';
                break;
        }
```

This assigns the `role` array property to the `$author_role` variable so you can check against it in the `switch` statement.

Here's what the `$authordata` object looks like:

```
WP_User Object
(
    [data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 25
            [user_login] => Name
            [user_pass] => hashedpassword
            [user_nicename] => name
            [user_email] => name@example.com
            [user_url] => 
            [user_registered] => 2015-03-27 00:00:00
            [user_activation_key] => 
            [user_status] => 0
            [display_name] => Name
        )

    [ID] => 25
    [caps] => Array
        (
            [author] => 1
        )

    [cap_key] => wp_capabilities
    [roles] => Array
        (
            [0] => author
        )

    [allcaps] => Array
        (
            [upload_files] => 1
            [edit_posts] => 1
            [edit_published_posts] => 1
            [publish_posts] => 1
            [read] => 1
            [level_2] => 1
            [level_1] => 1
            [level_0] => 1
            [delete_posts] => 1
            [delete_published_posts] => 1
            [edit_attachments] => 1
            [delete_attachments] => 1
            [read_others_attachments] => 1
            [edit_others_attachments] => 1
            [delete_others_attachments] => 1
            [edit_aggregator-records] => 1
            [edit_published_aggregator-records] => 1
            [delete_aggregator-records] => 1
            [delete_published_aggregator-records] => 1
            [publish_aggregator-records] => 1
            [author] => 1
        )

    [filter] => 
    [site_id:WP_User:private] => 1
)
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to use this as a function on a template:

```
function wp03052019_get_user_role() {
    $user_role = '';
    global $authordata;
    // This assumes that each user only has one role. You might have to adjust what array value you get
    $author_role = $authordata->roles[0];

        switch( $author_role ) {
            case 'talento_pro':
                $user_role = '<i title="Talento PRO" class="fa fa-bolt"></i>';
                break;
            case 'talento_pro_plus':
                $user_role =  '<i title="Talento PRO+" class="fa fa-rocket"></i>';
                break;
        }
    return $user_role;
}
```

You can then just put this in your `functions.php` and then call the function on any template you want this to output `echo wp03052019_get_user_role()`;

**SHORTCODE**

For a shortcode version, that you can call in the content editor, use the same function as above - only adding a single argument `$atts` - because it's required.

```
function wp03052019_get_user_role( $atts ) {
        $user_role = '';
        global $authordata;
        // This assumes that each user only has one role. You might have to adjust what array value you get
        $author_role = $authordata->roles[0];

            switch( $author_role ) {
                case 'talento_pro':
                    $user_role = '<i title="Talento PRO" class="fa fa-bolt"></i>';
                    break;
                case 'talento_pro_plus':
                    $user_role =  '<i title="Talento PRO+" class="fa fa-rocket"></i>';
                    break;
            }
        return $user_role;
    }

add_shortcode( 'userroleoutput', 'wp03052019_get_user_role');
```

Now, in your content editor, you can do `[userroleoutput /]`

Comment: Do you know how can I use the code above as a shortcode? Should I put the code on functions.php and pull it to other page through a shortcode? Is it possible with the `add_action()`? Thanks

Comment: Hello @disinfor could you help me a little bit with a function based on user roles? Do you have an email i can send it too or can I just put it here?